# Como guardar os resultados de uma função em um data.frame?

Tags: banco-de-dados, r, data.frame

Boa tarde

Estou utilizando o R para fazer uma análise temporal dos Coeficientes de Mortalidade Infantil (CMI) de cada Distrito Administrativo (n = 93) de São Paulo entre 2013 e 2019

A tabela base que estou utilizando tem os Anos nas linhas e cada distrito (93) é uma coluna.

Estou executando um algoritmo de análise temporal, "Prais_winsten", e ele retorna uma lista para mim como resultado.
Dessa lista, três valores são muito importantes e preciso utiliza-los ​​em uma fórmula no Excel para calcular equações de interesse.

Neste caso, estou rodando para 93 linhas (distritos administrativos) e guardando as listas que resultam em uma grande lista que chamei de pw_resultados

Então, eu os verifico um por um, pegando os valores de que preciso e reproduzindo-os em uma fórmula no Excel.
Estou começando no R mas tem me ajudado muito nas rotinas de trabalho com dados. Sou estagiário da Secretaria de Saúde do Município de São Paulo.

Bem, deixe-me mostrar meu script simples.

```
library(readxl)
library(prais)

CMI <- read_excel("cmi_da.xlsx", sheet = "CMI_DA")
CMI_lg <- read_excel("cmi_da.xlsx", sheet = "CMI_DA")

dataset_length <- length(names(CMI_lg))



pw_resultados <- c()
pw_resultados <- as.list(pw_resultados)


 for (i in 2:dataset_length) {
  CMI_lg[,i] <- log10(CMI_lg[,i])
}


 for (a in 2:dataset_length) {
    pw_resultados[[a]] <- summary(prais_winsten(as.vector(CMI_lg[,a]) ~ Ano, data = CMI_lg))
     }
```

Bom, o código roda tranquilamente e a única coisa chata é que o trabalho braçal de checar os resultados um por um é bem demorado e toma parte do meu tempo que poderia utilizar analisando os resultados.

```
pw_resultados[1]
pw_resultados[2]
pw_resultados[3]

#[...]

pw_resultados[93]
```

Em cada um desses comandos o R me retorna a seguinte lista:

```
pw_resultados[2]
#[[1]]
#
3Call:
#prais_winsten(formula = as.vector(CMI_lg[, a]) ~ Ano, data = CMI_lg)
#
#
#AR(1) coefficient rho after 5 Iterations: -0.6745
#
#Coefficients:
#             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
#(Intercept) 119.00927   35.23810   3.377   0.0197 *
#Ano          -0.05864    0.01748  -3.355   0.0202 *
#---
#Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
#
#Residual standard error: 0.1286 on 5 degrees of freedom
#Multiple R-squared:  0.8741,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.8489 
#F-statistic:  34.7 on 1 and 5 DF,  p-value: 0.002004
#
#Durbin-Watson statistic (original):  3.23 
#Durbin-Watson statistic (transformed): 1.945
```

Disso tudo, o que me interessa são os valores  da segunda linha do Coefficients

```
#Coefficients:
#             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
#(Intercept) 119.00927   35.23810   3.377   0.0197 *
#Ano          -0.05864   *0.01748  -3.355   *0.0202* *
#---
```

Eu precisava gerar um data.frame com a mesma indexação da tabela de dados que utilizei para rodar o prais_winsten que guardasse esses valores que imagino serem pw_resultados[a]$coefficients[2,]
Onde cada distrito ( ou coluna ) recebesse os respectivos valores de interesse da função prais_winsten

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Eu tentei dar uma olhada no código da função prais_winsten para ver se conseguia alterar alguma coisa mas sem sucesso.

Quem quiser, é só digitar no R:

```
getAnywhere(prais_winsten())
```

Para reproduzir os dados e rodar o código!

```
dput(head(CMI_lg, 20))

structure(list(Ano = c(2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019
), `Água Rasa` = c(0.889410289700751, 1.08051959681989, 0.74072475244302, 
0.913244817015834, 0.471083299722345, 0.793623937039851, 0.703334809738469
), `Alto de Pinheiros` = c(0.755722879198157, 0.977434172101259, 
0.518557371497695, 1.14721513131945, 0.838631997765025, 0.8843894883257, 
0.508638306165727), Anhanguera = c(1.09652242308326, 1.06472532963666, 
1.18009065048461, 1.02561392876918, 1.12726117252733, 0.739531088433941, 
0.87168152274032), Aricanduva = c(1.00363428465509, 1.00290499064341, 
0.807571944668793, 0.925183559354825, 1.02495133618423, 0.927750102386485, 
0.862092294568453), `Artur Alvim` = c(0.943412731479803, 1.03842072181893, 
1.03747282515619, 1.25701316667961, 1.32858714927555, 0.940677598585143, 
0.615467384505751), `Bela Vista` = c(1.05109823902979, 0.85959671983337, 
0.748118545447472, 0.707743928643524, 1.09258863922541, 0.362510270487489, 
1.15146878414735), Belém = c(0.475820321699244, 0.756135510565923, 
1.1204126517769, 1.10068468702332, 1.10110612760166, 0.947776467190093, 
0.800427645094796), `Bom Retiro` = c(0.968995718636463, 1.45017962676063, 
1.19044028536473, 0.552841968657781, 1.0276428555323, 1.1525815921406, 
0.761953896871205), Brás = c(1.2068307015529, 1.32483291033661, 
1.16510266065851, 0.892790030352132, 0.742321425130815, 0.939302159646388, 
1.28981751839029), Brasilândia = c(1.07666961476272, 1.12318754680854, 
1.18985152544628, 1.1808949674585, 1.07429679632844, 1.12575380312574, 
1.27670073184943), Cachoeirinha = c(1.10415513068501, 1.06314081917895, 
1.114450324994, 1.0122699104749, 1.13893405763383, 1.03794651487619, 
1.08182499483207), Cambuci = c(0.756961951313706, 0.872895201635192, 
1.0215151421378, 0.772113295386326, 0.999132278468773, 1.05469557834846, 
0.76870035458495), `Campo Belo` = c(0.944184972276588, 0.564899198187247, 
0.916190349770304, 0.951336277956313, 0.896196279044043, 0.997294106624075, 
0.862224038686528), `Campo Grande` = c(1.02064676997764, 0.983288003284806, 
0.694341600153948, 0.610125441609014, 0.98751428845194, 1.03803159082406, 
1.15308101609412), `Campo Limpo` = c(1.05263801687069, 1.07630863129053, 
1.03072049380803, 1.09236881130041, 1.06734178236535, 0.944942426999081, 
1.01968946772596), Cangaíba = c(0.97255331063729, 1.16880798731659, 
1.009328224934, 1.10769922855089, 1.04383156952464, 1.00656376950239, 
1.11476446206513), `Capão Redondo` = c(1.10658621149447, 1.02218310838668, 
1.06634402134245, 1.06923352826959, 1.02647911969302, 1.15885911248316, 
1.02451475630372), Carrão = c(1.17870487465837, 0.790932020475639, 
0.996108833763089, 0.831698985370571, 0.835647144215563, 0.903089986991944, 
1.04042865705561), `Casa Verde` = c(1.17050703331632, 0.98410704074001, 
0.797044866898648, 1.16869024447138, 1.11699410381146, 0.940562812148132, 
1.22184874961636), `Cidade Ademar` = c(1.0386254416402, 0.938830356795095, 
1.01161184215075, 1.01031808409215, 0.912103522054163, 1.05733403992828, 
1.16494389827988), `Cidade Dutra` = c(1.15078539379091, 0.830717528496593, 
1.12104757037139, 1.10852449147267, 1.10039226038454, 0.919091310235361, 
1.07789428084845), `Cidade Líder` = c(1.06902883297366, 1.01051149067825, 
0.823082300196537, 1.05082220664145, 1.01978996912998, 1.04849354432287, 
1.10612732120492), `Cidade Tiradentes` = c(1.17540607172149, 
1.1661717106378, 1.12968281486541, 1.11952940719622, 1.17881411739115, 
1.19263115453209, 1.06779207319325), Consolação = c(0.382999658879101, 
1.2518119729938, 0.981923936354205, 0.700057099977233, 1.0268721464003, 
0.404503778174426, 0.911273436046145), Cursino = c(1.11132138867934, 
1.14013516705334, 0.90626003378145, 0.837966921858781, 0.818156412055227, 
1.00639422256215, 1.04438096173187), `Ermelino Matarazzo` = c(1.19288505368104, 
0.96301643374683, 1.06184431045413, 0.965631098368738, 1.25326852376738, 
0.961578554357541, 1.24544079053786), `Freguesia do Ó` = c(1.03486552201917, 
1.02561392876918, 0.945855279325166, 1.21905584943219, 1.12355121312166, 
1.05340739099414, 1.02389287727924), Grajaú = c(1.07101219697208, 
1.08463120688645, 1.07870228875408, 1.11528735093212, 1.13838933469586, 
1.07457330380727, 1.10196588479794), Guaianases = c(0.921031695600134, 
1.13688966470977, 1.16567014340214, 0.997720233705101, 1.13033376849501, 
1.07314329105031, 1.21372192338566), Iguatemi = c(1.20466891192459, 
1.17016039183647, 1.04558518566577, 1.18082178614871, 1.09187257231644, 
1.1128048229587, 1.10827674789384), Ipiranga = c(0.870837626637017, 
0.711080394338273, 1.01378828448563, 1.0248555183169, 0.809668301829709, 
0.958911123515867, 0.904672118001818), `Itaim Bibi` = c(0.639406586434751, 
-0.0927206446840991, 0.757671582977971, 0.626720106722504, 0.664542099310616, 
0.194159451185327, 0.592779107072604), `Itaim Paulista` = c(1.09997443210192, 
1.15192090061068, 1.16626031504122, 1.09350099835296, 1.24955094715625, 
1.16066701563953, 1.08053921309315), Itaquera = c(1.13210416099597, 
1.17089323079309, 0.996691558412763, 0.99891561870778, 1.12011765677363, 
1.02214195902461, 1.07210273193442), Jabaquara = c(0.927573081101806, 
1.03165858460094, 0.970906235335186, 1.06859863760356, 0.848148791518876, 
0.838631997765025, 0.905147883412083), Jaçanã = c(1.0413258757616, 
1.22774816609227, 1.15417266597406, 1.00473052709303, 1.09799710864927, 
1.16115090926274, 1.14125055457313), Jaguara = c(0.505845405981557, 
1.1322379753498, 0.530177984021837, 0.54515513999149, 0.473660722610156, 
1.20901152491118, 0.846185135655471), Jaguaré = c(0.994604968113294, 
0.967582721167231, 0.848221690299056, 0.872895201635192, 1.05305672930217, 
0.968086835538289, 0.936613021135607), Jaraguá = c(1.11796361625377, 
1.14508697769214, 1.10933207898702, 1.15027355580367, 0.950648286553973, 
1.09137390771361, 1.07816907266677), `Jardim Ângela` = c(1.08373144931069, 
0.966648058400259, 1.11508280728043, 1.0730282410743, 0.947439234121226, 
0.976087842594589, 1.12306475535369), `Jardim Helena` = c(1.09860979788595, 
1.08701447989467, 1.04442835568422, 1.13041273830737, 1.10790539730952, 
1.15014203776444, 1.18597449298778), `Jardim Paulista` = c(0.359518563029578, 
0.83813309537598, 0.844663962534938, -3, 0.657577319177794, 0.786747947803603, 
0.106793246940152), `Jardim São Luís` = c(1.04187344718329, 1.03470820780651, 
1.0159621429031, 1.0332185011518, 1.13503906351263, 1.03684204148407, 
1.036651519664), `José Bonifácio` = c(1.08392222685853, 0.986419332348252, 
1.18782966232693, 1.1464538787461, 1.05525765999043, 1.2767496196169, 
1), Lajeado = c(1.13407310120698, 1.12301281557226, 1.16610489243066, 
1.22450157739747, 1.13667713987954, 1.17062474424858, 1.00300551013973
), Lapa = c(0.806875401645538, 0.554914977280646, 1.13130213956416, 
0.596879478824182, 0.791021482723747, 0.593459819566045, 0.702786804010359
), Liberdade = c(0.964856264118776, 0.399571674267869, 0.895626712428763, 
0.97061622231479, 0.931814138253838, 0.964856264118776, 0.912455190467573
), Limão = c(0.75913887056798, 1.23284413391782, 1.06994287507916, 
1.13386818266569, 0.755546157127803, 1.04836363757839, 1.04495398527707
), Mandaqui = c(0.981923936354205, 0.98471011740598, 0.900664722314042, 
1.02333264447843, 0.889410289700751, 0.95272513261582, 0.661942124580244
), Moema = c(0.0390538042661685, 0.670602120638957, 0.902098446648216, 
0.580044251510242, 0.66354026615147, 0.546172223552139, 0.396855627379818
), Mooca = c(0.786039762596694, 0.722620025332745, 0.837350262013517, 
0.653647025549361, 1.0301183562535, 0.882728704344236, 0.981923936354205
), Morumbi = c(0.70060166993185, 0.599749908849888, 0.603800652904264, 
0.761953896871205, 0.890759031411797, 0.903785414653595, 1.22112552799726
), Parelheiros = c(1.2528472404254, 1.07692876612709, 1.00485250279441, 
1.10154076727485, 1.00530585556893, 1.05322033619125, 1.11517132998237
), Pari = c(0.988570538219218, 1.07701518429112, 1.37380632895532, 
1.14569395819892, 1.10237290870956, 1.18842499412941, 1.15490195998574
), `Parque do Carmo` = c(1.10964885401428, 1.19893947015214, 
1.28330122870355, 1.12675207737177, 1.09799710864927, 1.29132051427747, 
1.0173176978508), Pedreira = c(1.07589308722155, 0.968328140724491, 
0.998194199136738, 0.954490748646943, 1.0924403905529, 1.14014534849493, 
1.0434474080826), Penha = c(1.12731409976911, 1.1518108830086, 
1.10605339244793, 0.995409962749524, 0.913131925286084, 0.859334860023264, 
1.05771629194977), Perus = c(1.17333632333518, 1.28515016164333, 
0.941048654554661, 1.12365384075418, 1.27748359728341, 1.03151705144606, 
1.03352303414366), Pinheiros = c(0.18309616062434, 0.484126156288321, 
0.202040356262804, 0.493494967595128, 0.645891560852599, 0.484788695672198, 
0.685430605699544), Pirituba = c(1.16476252659969, 0.988923193116309, 
1.05826777708026, 0.972941767265964, 1.09052321434666, 1.0374453807199, 
1.12951248812106), `Ponte Rasa` = c(1.00504022463952, 1.10031626169997, 
1.12732966783256, 0.986779630601337, 1.20605448243312, 1.1644959410644, 
1.04215336629185), `Raposo Tavares` = c(0.731422028117157, 1.10100072911021, 
1.10597304937455, 1.0232398881333, 0.931566747485597, 1.01572278426283, 
0.832951328719658), República = c(1.34678748622466, 1.31811297145426, 
1.20481541031758, 1.19156394571189, 1.01999662841625, 1.38457604711406, 
0.807571944668793), `Rio Pequeno` = c(1.01062435097526, 0.901933409792001, 
1.04195401146535, 0.875944321217602, 0.847915597617359, 1.11373494097024, 
1.00534074846911), Sacomã = c(1.01606525665113, 0.962105007427209, 
1.03197288405879, 1.03488276037359, 0.879060654820633, 1.03151705144606, 
0.984273596631564), `Santa Cecília` = c(1.14417809459397, 0.825358807339552, 
0.974182296747991, 1.12090412049993, 0.937686679239671, 0.67726399553005, 
0.983488963207833), Santana = c(0.997667764726292, 0.75448733218585, 
1.04985991634324, 0.967307996129981, 1.04427525539524, 0.92959267825988, 
0.991399828238082), `Santo Amaro` = c(0.340559218129682, 0.991873173769304, 
0.964570261815452, 0.918241331064565, 0.894733185638134, 0.67520328237827, 
1.06651271215129), `São Domingos` = c(0.777655197237876, 1.02368529937552, 
0.991045157347074, 1.20180990017785, 1.15645578805436, 0.739531088433941, 
0.923642787473374), `São Lucas` = c(0.982230360188199, 1.21872345062415, 
1.15801519540989, 0.914913387715637, 1.03976712687149, 1.10106597277921, 
0.917767167266863), `São Mateus` = c(1.2277140803878, 1.09972099034188, 
0.997114311762512, 1.11826570675555, 1.07643442729826, 1.1178979722019, 
0.964665574990838), `São Miguel` = c(0.981923936354205, 1.07340034609297, 
0.957293260943944, 0.711080394338273, 1.07409108920461, 1.03899790691338, 
1.30697693207631), `São Rafael` = c(1.12737386408578, 1.09151498112135, 
1.05971344244344, 1.05990514162197, 1.13096395248765, 1.07706320181363, 
1.15277448331939), Sapopemba = c(1.0546299055097, 1.01183756858322, 
1.00232243591903, 1.06267020925546, 1.05520898954657, 1.12048216546383, 
1.08652433931299), Saúde = c(0.204467557289846, 0.926781700926052, 
0.599634726650061, 0.821023052706831, 0.741636417919552, 0.817799408761879, 
0.818871300252705), Socorro = c(0.704432900037521, 1.08407278830288, 
1.0054628957015, 1.20065945054642, 0.405607449624573, 1.26875668980846, 
1.28122160231043), Tatuapé = c(0.945004138470859, 0.874751163784164, 
0.931350396104165, 1.03715731879876, 1.03668448861389, 1.03621217265444, 
0.727230413448241), Tremembé = c(1.0333369052753, 1.1200762254967, 
1.05933029774995, 1.18045606445813, 1.13487026572887, 0.981143532762533, 
1.21225890010466), Tucuruvi = c(0.897480541631663, 0.928527125537984, 
1.00796892967128, 0.91721462968355, 0.980883709552927, 0.698102282804792, 
1.0204516252959), `Vila Andrade` = c(0.934295827760483, 0.894319537054191, 
0.922199659668761, 0.789770685161635, 0.953611267348683, 0.928955267836381, 
0.649399612898512), `Vila Curuçá` = c(1.10060316509556, 1.12022663452049, 
1.01239993345536, 1.09999721237321, 1.2459006761624, 1.07590540221728, 
0.976649538677527), `Vila Formosa` = c(1.01682492796219, 1.19637220465518, 
1.14482710265782, 1.16430942850757, 1.00921730819686, 1.09375477196462, 
1.11163326982876), `Vila Guilherme` = c(0.898645775001184, 0.846693379694639, 
1.01472325682071, 1.11690664142431, 0.925497016230146, 1.08301995267962, 
0.701692862671492), `Vila Jacuí` = c(1.15490195998574, 1.15554424920595, 
1.11874706070966, 1.19546108673978, 1.22870210076027, 1.16977805667496, 
1.17500687776346), `Vila Leopoldina` = c(0.790484985457369, 0.633888476621653, 
0.45717457304082, 0.22767829327708, 0.519993057042849, 0.708483153472048, 
0.578396073130169), `Vila Maria` = c(1.18619669533691, 1.15247140706278, 
1.07507492276797, 1.19044028536473, 1.08238947425013, 1.01412464269161, 
1.14468279480406), `Vila Mariana` = c(0.723210054910576, 0.776309409979935, 
0.594141600682363, 0.619788758288394, 0.491133749061542, 0.867171303532789, 
0.758382376069374), `Vila Matilde` = c(0.917867704215493, 0.948525897025594, 
0.854803593885818, 1.06081366765978, 0.78847900275977, 0.944135375464805, 
1.09080068082562), `Vila Medeiros` = c(1.10237290870956, 1.04287180232319, 
1.07169322465507, 1.1004649672251, 0.932557157223619, 1.13715334001706, 
1.06143262607894), `Vila Prudente` = c(0.895512888687605, 1.054203273952, 
0.725182629756266, 1.04852370680383, 0.885055584287415, 1.11350927482752, 
0.981230175053475), `Vila Sônia` = c(0.953374787908098, 1.06816757604767, 
0.72558555133039, 0.968303063813556, 0.725265015127262, 1.18982860289474, 
0.97557297715703), MSP = c(1.04743175054596, 1.04564878847353, 
1.03619246290464, 1.05319039610875, 1.04899586739949, 1.04186635058655, 
1.04870246334299)), row.names = c(NA, 7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: O `getAnywhere` só funciona se o pacote onde a função existe estiver carregado. Por favor edite a pergunta com `library(prais)` no início do script. E com a saída de `dput(head(CMI_lg, 20))`.

Comment: Olá Rui creio que esteja no pacote prais. No inicio do código já está library(prais).

Comment: Adicionei o output de dput(head(CMI_lg, 20)) como sugerido por @RuiBarradas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creio que o seguinte responde à questão.
Em vez de um ciclo `for`, faz-se um ciclo `lapply` com os nomes das variáveis resposta. Aí o mais difícil é ter nomes de coluna com caracteres especiais. O `paste0` serve para ter esses nomes entre ``` "``" ```. Depois forma-se a fórmula das regressões e ajusta-se o modelo. Finalmente, extrai-se a segunda linha e sai do ciclo também com o nome da coluna.

```
library(prais)

pw_resultados <- lapply(names(CMI_lg)[-1], function(a){
  resp <- paste0("`", a, "`")
  fmla <- paste(resp, "Ano", sep = "~")
  fmla <- as.formula(fmla)
  pw <- prais_winsten(fmla, data = CMI_lg)
  cf <- coef(summary(pw))[2, ]
  cbind.data.frame(coluna = a, t(cf))
})
pw_resultados <- do.call(rbind, pw_resultados)

head(pw_resultados)
#             coluna    Estimate Std. Error    t value   Pr(>|t|)
#1         Água Rasa -0.05863596 0.01747921 -3.3546116 0.02022661
#2 Alto de Pinheiros -0.01258421 0.02634637 -0.4776450 0.65305285
#3        Anhanguera -0.05251868 0.01778158 -2.9535432 0.03175499
#4        Aricanduva -0.01188546 0.01479517 -0.8033337 0.45825314
#5       Artur Alvim -0.04345656 0.05855142 -0.7421949 0.49134155
#6        Bela Vista -0.03202344 0.01965581 -1.6292095 0.17860096
```

Comment: Você testou e deu certo aí? Obtive erros aqui, precisa de algum pacote que você não especificou?                                                                                                                    > linha2 <- lapply(pw_resultados, function(res) coef(summary(res))[2, ])
Erro: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
> linhas2 <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, linha2)
Error in do.call(rbind.data.frame, linha2) : 
  objeto 'linha2' não encontrado
> linhas2 <- cbind.data.frame(coluna = names(CMI_lg)[-1], linhas2)

Comment: @LuccaNielsen Veja agora, testado com os dados acima e não deu erros.

Comment: Muito obrigado, deu certo! Parabéns pela velocidade e prestatividade amigo